# Can a serverless build service (e.g. AWS CodeBuild) used to build Android AOSP ROMs?

Tags: gnu-make, android-source, serverless, aws-codebuild

As far as I understand, AWS CodeBuild is frequently used to build Android apps.

**Could a serverless build service like e.g. CodeBuild also be used to build a complete custom ROMs based on AOSP?**

The output should be the device specific image files, e.g. boot.img, system.img, ...

The idea is to avoid to set up and maintain an own (virtual) machine with the full AOSP build environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, but probably not. It *requires* 16GB of RAM to build the AOSP. This is a hard requirement. I've tried it with less. You can get away with 12GB and 4GB of swap, but 4GB with 12 of swap doesn't work....

Anyway, why does this matter?

Because [the largest compute available for AWS Code Build is 15GB](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/pricing/).

It's also just impractical. The source code for AOSP is ~80GB in size. It takes hours to download it all. You don't want to do that every time. At most, you want to sync with the latest changes and move on.

AWS instances are also virtualized. This has a huge impact on the build time.

As much as I love the cloud, if you want to set up a build server for AOSP, your best bet is to purchase a decent linux workstation to act as your build server. It's a bit of up front cost, but you'll get it back 100 fold in development time saved.